# jsf-console 3.x on JBoss 6.x possible?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, javassist

I'm trying to move an application from JBoss 4.2.2 AS to 6.x AS. Right now I'm trying to get jbpm 3.x running on the AS I have this problem when trying to upload a .par file to the server:

13:41:51,713 ERROR [org.jbpm.db.GraphSession] (http-127.0.0.1-8888-1) java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jbpm.graph.def.Node_$$_javassist_92 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject

Which then results in:
13:41:51,740 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/app].[ProcessUploadServlet]] (http-127.0.0.1-8888-1) Servlet.service() for servlet ProcessUploadServlet threw exception: org.jbpm.JbpmException: couldn't find process definition 'ProcessName'.

I've tried using both old and new versions of javassist which has no positive effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using eclipse plugins and you have class loader problem between 2 plugins, make sure that you have only one class loader to load ProxyObject (Javassist)